# What is making my widget's infinite loop stop working?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

My widget is a blank background that switches between two colors with a 333ms delay between each switch. It works fine at first, but after 158 switches, it stops switching colors. The thing is, I don't rely on onUpdate. Everything's in an infinite while-loop which is first called when I put the widget on my home screen. What could be causing it to stop switching after 158 switches? Could changing the background color like this be too costly, and the OS disables my widget?

ColorSwitchWidget.java:

```
public class ColorSwitchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.color_switch_widget);

        boolean lightOn = true;

        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(333);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
            }

            if (lightOn) {
                views.setInt(R.id.RelativeLayout1, "setBackgroundColor", Color.argb(150, 255, 248, 231)); //color 1
                lightOn = false;
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            } else {
                views.setInt(R.id.RelativeLayout1, "setBackgroundColor", Color.argb(220, 255, 248, 231)); //color 2
                lightOn = true;
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager, appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    }
}
```

color_switch_widget_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/color_switch_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/color_switch_widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_icon_blink"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```

The widget works... just not for very long. Is the infinite loop a poor choice?

**Edit: Found a workaround that doesn't use Thread.sleep(). I'm not sure if this will cause problems or memory issues, but it seems to work for now.**

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable blinkRunnable = new Runnable(){
    int lightOff = true;
    public void run(){
        if(lightOff){
            lightOff = false;
            views.setInt(R.id.RelativeLayout1, "setBackgroundColor", Color.argb(220, 255, 248, 231)); //light "on"
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 333);
        } else{
            lightOff = true;
            views.setInt(R.id.RelativeLayout1, "setBackgroundColor", Color.argb(150, 255, 248, 231)); //light "off"
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 333);
        }
    }
};

//start the loop
myHandler.post(blinkRunnable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the fact that you don't run it on a custom thread. The method is called from the main thread, and when you pause the main thread(`Thread.sleep()`) Android thinks the application isn't responding.

Use a new thread instead by creating a new class and letting it extend Thread

Comment: Just found out about how bad it is to Thread.sleep() here... I also tried putting Thread.sleep(1000) it in its own thread, but it doesn't seem to delay the setBackground code. My guess is the other thread slept while the main thread just kept on going.

Comment: Secondary threads run their own thread, so of course the main thread keeps running. THat's the point. BLock the main thread and your app will get ANR and possibly crash. Heavy operations should always be done on a thread that isn't the main thread